# Pinch or Zoom then tapping quit iPad app - Terminated due to memory err

Tags: ios, angularjs, ipad, backbone.js, pinchzoom

I have created iPad application  with pinch and zoom feature using AngularJs framework. For pinch & zoom feature, I have added this meta tag,

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.5, user-scalable=yes">
```

My application quit unexpectedly with the below error message  when (double) tapping after pinching or zooming.

> Terminated due to memory error

Comment: What is the crash log?

Comment: I am getting error: "Terminated due to memory error"